# How to centering selected item on screen in horizontal listview in flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my app, I have Column with horizontal ListView and PageView. The ListView is like tabs in TabBar and those tabs control behaviour of pages below.
And everything works fine, except for one moment.

I need to centre selected items of horizontal ListView.
I want to understand how to realize such behaviour like on the video below. I want to repeat behaviour of ListView which contains: "All", "classics", "documentaries", etc.

[video with example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxmIb_gAwDc)

Somebody recommend NotificationListener, but I don't understand how to use it properly.
Is anyone a solution?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please, attach your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a scroll controller.
create a scrollController :

```
final scrollController = ScrollController();
```

add it to your ListView:

```
ListView(
controller: scrollController,
),
```

then, to scroll the selected item to the center of the screen, use :

```
scrollController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
```

You can change 0 to the offset of the item and add half width of the screen into it. Example:

```
scrollController.animateTo( itemWidth + MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
```

This is my workaround. You can use it for better understanding:

```
final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    final scrollController = ScrollController();
ListView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            controller: scrollController,
            children: <Widget>[
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello 1',
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async{
                  await scrollController.animateTo(0, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello 2',
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async{
                  await scrollController.animateTo(0.5*width + 24, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello 3',
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async{
                  await scrollController.animateTo(1.5*width + 24, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello 4',
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async{
                  await scrollController.animateTo(2.5*width + 24, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello 5',
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async{
                  await scrollController.animateTo(3.5*width + 24, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  width: width,
                  child: Text(
                    'Hello 6',
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async{
                  await scrollController.animateTo(4.5*width + 24, duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.easeIn);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer may be useful for me. But what if I need to build items inside ListView dynamically? And how to deal with the first and last two elements, because they shouldn't be centered?

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the question is much easier than I thought.
To achieve this behaviour, which I mentioned earlier, you need to build a Column with a TabBar and a TabBarView.

You can click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v8QXhMZNPQE) to see how it look's like.

And here you can see my exapmle:

````
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    tabController = TabController(length: 10, vsync: this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        TabBar(
          controller: tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          labelColor: Colors.black,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
          indicatorPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6),
          indicator: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.yellow,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
          ),
          enableFeedback: true,
          tabs: List.generate(
            10,
            (i) => Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
              child: Tab(
                text: i.toString(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: TabBarView(
            controller: tabController,
            children: List.generate(
              10,
              (index) => Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60,
                  color: Colors.yellow,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      index.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 horizontal listview and 1 pageview. When user click listview item you can get index and then you can equal it to the viewpager selected item.

Example code :
When user click listview item

```
controller.animateToPage( currentListViewIndex,
                           duration:const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                           curve: Curves.ease);
```

and use https://pub.dev/packages/expandable_page_view this library for pagerview

Expandable page view code:

```
ExpandablePageView(
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    itemCount: 5,
                    controller: controller,
                    onPageChanged: (var index) {
                      currentListViewIndex = index;
                    },
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                       return Container();
                    },
                  )
```

Comment: @ DavudSeyfullayev Thank you much! But I think you misunderstood me.

I need to centring selected items of horizontal ListView rather than pages of PageView.
I want to repeat behaviour of ListView from video which contains: "All", "classics", "documentaries", etc.