# Flutter - Scroll ListView selected item into the center of the screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a horizontal scrolling ListView with an undetermined number of items inside.

[image]

How can I programatically scroll a specific item into the center of my screen?

Context: On the previous screen I have multiple items, and when I click on one, I need it to navigate to this screen and scroll the item selected on the previous screen to the center of the new screen.

My trouble is really just with the scrolling part.

Thanks in advance.

ListView:

```
final listViewController = ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.separated(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
      controller: listViewController,
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      itemCount: testArray.length,
      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => Item(
        testArray[i],
        testArray[i] == 'item5' ? true : false,
        () => {
          // testing code for the scroll functionality
          listViewController.animateTo(
              i + MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
              curve: Curves.easeIn),
        },
      ),
      separatorBuilder: (ctx, i) => Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Item Widget:

```
class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  final String itemName;
  final bool selectedItem;
  final VoidCallback navigationHandler;

  Item(
      this.itemName, this.selectedItem, this.navigationHandler);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      child: TextButton(
        onPressed: navigationHandler,
        child: Text(
          itemName,
          style: selectedItem
              ? Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6?.copyWith(
                    fontSize: 22,
                  )
              : Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6?.copyWith(
                    color: Color(0xff707070),
                  ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet? do you know the item size?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68944136/1897466

Comment: Hey @YeasinSheikh , my code is just a ListView.builder with items that come from a database, so I don't know the number of items. I also don't know the size of each item given that they are text widgets and all the text value will be of different sizes.

Comment: @AlexChengalan I had already checked out this question, I'm not sure it actually answers my question though.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh updated with code snippet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution to this issue that I've found is to use the package [scrollable_positioned_list](https://pub.dev/packages/scrollable_positioned_list) which can scroll to items based on its index.

If you knew the extent of its children you could have used a `FixedExtentScrollController` as the controller of your lisview and would not have needed to rely on a external dependency.

The gist of using the package is just to  create a controller , this time an
`ItemScrollController` and just replace your `ListView.separated` to `ScrollablePositionedList.separated`

```
final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();

ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
  itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
...
);
```

One then can scroll to a particular item with:

```
itemScrollController.scrollTo(
 index: 150,
 duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
 curve: Curves.easeIn);
```

A complete example would be as follows

```
final testArray = [for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) 'item$i'];

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: MyApp._title,
        home: Scaffold(
            body: ScrollablePositionedList.separated(
          itemCount: testArray.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          itemBuilder: (context, i) => Item(
            testArray[i],
            testArray[i] == 'item5' ? true : false,
            () => {
              // testing code for the scroll functionality
              itemScrollController.scrollTo(
                  index: (i + 5) % testArray.length,
                  duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                  curve: Curves.easeIn,
                  alignment: 0.5),/// Needed to center the item when scrolling
         
            },
          ),
          itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
          separatorBuilder: (ctx, i) => Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6)),
        )));
  }
}
```

By the way be accustomed at whenever you're working with controllers create them in the State of a Stateful widget, so they are only created once, and dispose them if necessary. I'ts not the case with `ItemScrollController` but `ScrollController` would have needed to be disposed .

Comment: hey @croxx5f Thanks a lot, this worked great! I used the ScrollablePositionedList given that the children's sizes are always different. The only remaining problem is that the alignment property doesn't give me my desired result.. alignment: 0.5 sends the first pixel of the child to the center, and not the center of my child to center. Do you know any way in which I can achieve this? Thanks for your great answer!

Comment: Unfortunately its not possible to modify the alignment to the center of the item without forking/vendoring the library, which would not be much of a hassle though. You'll probably need to modify the `_startScroll` at `scrollable_positioned_list.dart`  and change `final localScrollAmount = itemPosition.itemLeadingEdge *
          primary.scrollController.position.viewportDimension;`  to `... (itemPosition.itemLeadingEdge + itemPosition.itemTrailingEdge)/2 *...`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49153087/flutter-scrolling-to-a-widget-in-listview) the easiest way would be to set a `GlobalKey` for each list item and use `ensureVisible` to scroll, with `alignment: 0.5` that item will be center at the scroll

```
Scrollable.ensureVisible(itemKey.currentContext, alignment: 0.5);
```

If you need to scroll after build then:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => 
    Scrollable.ensureVisible(itemKey.currentContext, alignment: 0.5))
```